# Bootstrap dropdown-menu is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello my bootstrap `nav` is not dropping down into different sections like I've seen it in examples on multiple sites. I've tried moving things around but to no avail. I feel like I'm missing something very simple though so any input would be much obliged :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

AN EXAMPLE :D

https://jsfiddle.net/pajdnLwv/

Comment: Can you please provide a code starting point, using CodePen or JSFiddle. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There ya go      adfdaf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed loading the following JS libraries to make the dropdown menu work:

- jQuery library (to get the Bootstrap JS work)
- Bootstrap JS (to get the dropdown work)

See a working solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeg9dbjm/)

Add this to your `<head>` to get it working:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you XD I don't know why I forgot that I've used bootstrap like 20 times now

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. For your next project, be sure to add the whole Bootstrap package (jQuery, JS, CSS) at once.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to include the javascript files in your head tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can try it [here](http://liveweave.com/o3xzNC)

Comment: Thank you XD I don't know why I forgot that I've used bootstrap like 20 times now

Comment: Np.. Its these very minor things we usually overlook and later realize. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer** for anyone using **Bootstrap 4**.

Please note that in Bootstrap 4, dropdown menus depend on the `popper.js` library as well (the `umd` version specifically). So to get them to work, you need jquery, popper, and bootstrap loaded, in that order. As of today, that looks like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Source: [Bootstrap Docs > Introduction > Quick Start](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)